# Ninject Pass Delegate into WithConstructorArgument

Tags: c#, ninject, ioc-container, ninject-2

I have a need to point to a method in Ninject bindings as part of a constructor argument. The constructor for the class looks like this:

```
MyObject(Func<Populator> param1, TimeSpan time)
```

I have been looking and haven't been able to find a way to bind the delegate for the Func. Is this even possible?  Ninject wouldn't let me do this because its expecting an object as an argument, and won't take a delegate.

```
Bind<IInterface>()
      .To<MyObject>()
      .InSingletonScope()
      .WithConstructorArgument
            ("param1", ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<OtherWiredObject>().PopMethod)
      .WithConstructorArgument
            ("time", new TimeSpan(0,30,0));
```

Is there a way to get this behavior to work in Ninject?

Comment: that overload appears to be for a callback function. What if you did `() => Kernel.Get<OtherWiredObject>().PopMethod`?

Comment: No dice, wired it in as '() => Kernel.Get<OtherWiredObject>().PopMethod' Looking at the WithConstructorArgument method signature for this, the Func expects an object to be returned, and I need to return a Func to the parameter. Perhaps there is another way around this?

Comment: is `PopMethod` a property of type `Populator`?

Comment: if `PopMethod` is a function which returns `Populator` then add `()` to the end of it...there by making a valid `Func<Populator>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a binding like this:

```
Bind<Func<Populator>>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<OtherWiredObject>().PopMethod);
```